# Is there a better way to check the equivalence of expressions than I do here

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I had a complicated expression which had manipulated into a different form, so I used `FullSimplify[(expr1)==(expr2)]` to check I hadn't made a mistake, and was surprised it wasn't simplifed to `True`. I reduced the statement to :

`FullSimplify[(2 a == -b) == (-2 a == b)]`

and got this result :

`(-2 a == b) == (2 a + b == 0)`.

I get much the same using
`Reduce[]`

Is this expression not always `True`?
Did I do something wrong?

Is there a better way for me to check equivalence of expressions?

Comment: Try `FullSimplify[(2 a === -b) == (-2 a === b)]` gives `True` The 3 `=` is `SameQ`  See the difference between `2 a === -b` and `2 a == -b`

Comment: An alternative might be to ask for a counterexample and find none, eg as in `FindInstance[(2 a == -b) != (-2 a == b), {a, b}]`, which returns an empty set.

Comment: It might be better to use boolean relations between boolean-valued expressions. For instance, `FullSimplify[Equivalent[2 a == -b, -2 a == b]]`.

Comment: You indicate that `(2 a == -b) == (-2 a == b)` is a particular example from a more general set of problems. Should `(-2 a == b) == (2 a c == -c b)` be considered `True` or `False`? (They have the same solution set for `c != 0` but not for `c == 0`.) -- *Is this expression not always `True`?* It's true for all numbers, but not if, say, `a = Indeterminate` per the docs for `Equal`. I don't think that satisfactorily explains why it does not simplify though, since `x == x` evaluates to `True` but `Indeterminate == Indeterminate` does not.

Comment: `FullSimplify[Equivalent[2 a == -b, -2 a == b]]` is exactly the intention I had.

Comment: However, if `FullSimplify[Equivalent[2 a == -b, -2 a == b]]` return to `True`, I would would have expected to `FullSimplify[Implies[-2 a == b, 2 a c == -b c]]` return `True` too. Note `Reduce[Implies[-2 a == b, 2 a c == -b c]]` is reduced to `True` as is `Reduce[Equivalent[2 a == -b, -2 a == b]]`.

Comment: The  Doc for `FindInstance` (which @MarcoB) suggested says that it returns a result the same form as `Solve` if one exists, and otherewise returns the empty set `{}`. The way I read it, it implies that it guarantees to return an empty set if and only if no instance exists. And so it should work. Indeed, it does not find an instance for `FindInstance[! Implies[-2 a == b, 2 a c == -b c], {a, b, c}]`, i.e. I think `FindInstance[ ! . ] `it agrees with `Reduce[ . ]`, but not `FullSimplify[ . ]`. Perhaps there are different assumptions for `FullSimplify[ . ]`?

Comment: `Reduce[c > 0 && c < 100 && Implies[-2 a == b, 2 a c == -b c] || ! (c > 0 && c < 100)]` returns `2 a + b != 0 && 0 < c < 100) || (0 < c < 100 && a == -(b/2)) || 
 c >= 100 || c <= 0` which although `True` is not simple. However, `FullSimplify[
 Reduce[c > 0 && c < 100 && 
    Implies[-2 a == b, 2 a c == -b c] || ! (c > 0 && c < 100)]]` is -- it returns `True`!.

Comment: @AndyAckland I think you might want to turn your last few comments into a self-answer, so they are retained. Comments are ephemeral and not searchable, and self-answers are encouraged on this site.

Comment: @Nasser - your `FullSimplify` returns `True` because `False == False` is `True`

Comment: @JasonB. Yes, that is correct.  But that is what OP wanted, isn't?

Comment: @Nasser - no.  They want it to return `True` because the two equations are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
ApplySides[Reduce,(2 a == -b) == (-2 a == b)]

ApplySides[Solve[#,b]&,(2 a == -b) == (-2 a == b)]

(* True
   True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found two useful expressions that reduce to `True` if I'm my thinking is correct :

- `Reduce[Implies[-2 a == b, 2 a c == -b c]]`.
- `Reduce[Equivalent[-2 a == b || c == 0, 2 a c == -b c]]`.

Nither `Refine[.]`, `Simplify[.]`, nor `FullSimplify[.]` do what I want.

Comment: What did you expect? `-2a == b` is not "equal" to `2a == b`. They're two different equations. But they are equivalent.